# How to make the spritesheet exporter for easeljs/createjs in flashCC works with easel 7.0?

Tags: html, flash, createjs, sprite-sheet

Flash CC html5 exporter uses easeljs 7.0.

In this version the BitmapAnimation is deprecated and replaced by Sprite.

However, the spritesheet exporter for easeljs of flash cc still uses BitmapAnimation, making it incompatible.

Am I missing something ?
Does anyone have run into this and solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EaselJS up to v0.7.1 still supports `BitmapAnimation` via an alias back to `Sprite`. The current version of FlashCC uses `Sprite`, however it is not compatible with EaselJS v0.8.0 due to dependency on the old inheritance model. The vNEXT of EaselJS is compatible with it, and we are working with Adobe to update FlashCC's export format to be more flexible and forward compatible.

The spritesheet data exported is still completely compatible, just not the `Sprite` it generates. In the worst case, you can just copy the data out, and write the code to instantiate the Sprite yourself.

Comment: thanks gskinner.
I confirm that using the alias trick and using the 8.0 NEXT version works like a charm with BitmapAnimation.